# What is the meaning of "follow" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> Moreover, although these opinions appear to **follow** logically in a dialectical discussion, yet to believe
>   them seems next door to madness when one considers the facts. For indeed no lunatic seems to be
>   so far out of his senses.
>
> - Aristotle, On Generation and Corruption

What is the meaning of "follow" in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Follow logically” in this sense would mean that a certain line of thought has led him to his conclusion. You can think of “follow” in this context as continuing down a line of thought.